# pretty url with folder name and two variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

ugly url - `example.com/folder_name/art.php?id=9&s=something`
want to be - `example.com/folder_name/id/s`

here is my try

```
# external
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+art\.php\?id=([^&]*)&s=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

# internal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ art.php?id=$1&s=$2  [L]
```

doesn't work
entering ugly url - address bar is unchanged
entering pretty url - getting error 404

pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rules will have to allow `folder_name` as well so use:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

# external
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(folder_name)/art\.php\?id=([^&]*)&s=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

# internal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(folder_name)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1/art.php?id=$2&s=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This assumes there is no other .htaccess in `folder_name/`.

In case there is a .htaccess inside that subfolder then use this .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /folder_name/

# external
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /art\.php\?id=([^&]*)&s=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

# internal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ art.php?id=$1&s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: `folder_name` is various, it is a string

Comment: So where is the problem, just change `folder_name` with whatever and use it

Comment: `htaccess` is in root - `example.com` - from there I have various folders. Inside each folder is an `art.php` there is no `htaccess` inside folders

Comment: solved - `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^\s&]*)/art\.php\?id=([^&]*)&s=([^\s&]*) [NC]  RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]`